# Corsair & G.Skill DDR4 Ram compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard

**My configuration:**
**Processor:** G4560 
**Motherboard:** MSI B250M PRO-VH

Can I use these two rams in dual channel ?

[Corsair DDR4 2400 8GB](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE%C2%AE-LPX-8GB-%281x8GB%29-DDR4-DRAM-2400MHz-C14-Memory-Kit---Red/p/CMK8GX4M1A2400C14R)

[G.Skill DDR 2400 4GB](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f4-2400c15s-4gnt)

I know that both of them need same speed, timing & voltage to use in dual channel mode. I couldn't find any timing in their specs & their latencies are different . Will different latency cause a problem?

I have DIMM A1 & DIMM B1 slots in motherboard. Where should I put which ram for better performance ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **"latency"** parameter you see in their specifications are the timings (if they are 4 numbers like 1-2-3-4).

Different timings **will** cause a problem and latency is one parameter of the RAM timings.
Insert the RAM sticks into two different channels (one into channel A, and the other one into channel B), since they can't work together in dual-channel, however, this won't really make a difference for performance in your case.

Explaining timings:
Timings are usually written down in the `a-b-c-d` (`CL-tRCD-tRP-tRAS`) format.
The abbreviations for those timings are as follows:

> **CL: CAS Latency**. The time it takes between a command having been sent    to the memory and when it begins to reply to it. It is the
>   time it    takes between the processor asking for some data from the
>   memory and    then returning it.
>   **tRCD: RAS to CAS Delay**. The time it takes between    the activation of the line (RAS) and the column (CAS) where the data
>   are stored in the matrix.
>   **tRP: RAS Precharge**. The time it takes    between disabling the access to a line of data and the beginning of    the access to another
>   line of data.
>   **tRAS: Active to Precharge Delay**.    How long the memory has to wait until the next access to the memory    can be initiated.

<sub>If you want to read more:

Source: [Hardware Secrets - Understanding RAM Timings](https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/understanding-ram-timings/)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dual channel you also need the same size memory sticks.

What you will get with an 8GB and 4GB stick will either be single-channel or might be "[flex mode](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005657/boards-and-kits.html#flex)" where the lower 4GB of you 8GB stick will operate in dual channel mode with the 4GB stick. The remaining 4GB will be operating as single channel.

Depending on your workload this may result in random and unpredictable slowdowns.

I cannot find any information on whether your processor supports this memory mode.

Comment: If I use two of the same G.Skill 4GB Ram , what will be the performance ?

Comment: If you use two identical sticks of RAM then you will get dual-channel. The performance will be twice that of a single stick of RAM.